# Rendering Markdown containing images using react/webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, markdown

I'm currently developing a blog using react and Webpack and need some advice. I'm storing the contents of each blog entry as markdown in a database, the markdown for any given entry may contain a number of images and this is where my problem lies.

What I wrongfully assumed when choosing this approach is that when I converted the markdown to HTML, the images would resolve themselves correctly. However due to my limited experience using Webpack it turns out this is not the case and instead assets must be manually imported first, great.

I've tried using the markdown loader for Webpack, but of course this requires more manual importing of .md files which I wanted to avoid.

Essentially, is there a better approach to this or is there some way to load images without importing them using Webpack?

Comment: "instead assets must be manually imported first" That doesn't sound right. Have you read the [Asset Management guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/) in the webpack docs?

Comment: I have, what I meant by manually importing is having to "import someImg from ./Images/someImg.jpg" and then having to use the someImg variable name to render the image, I'd like to continue to use the path where my assets are kept so that images are picked up in the Markdown.

Comment: Again, I'm not so au fait with Webpack, I'm only using it because I'm learning React.

Comment: You might want to look into copy-webpack-plugin, which will let you just copy them en mass to wherever you need them.

Comment: I think I'm going to just store the MD files somewhere as assets, import them and select the right one based off the current route or something, I don't really want to add anymore boiler plate or layers of abstraction for something as simple as a blog.